# Yii Ajax form validate only for one field

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I have an email field in my model registration form and other fields like name, country, age.

and I have to do an **ajax validation** onChange event only **for email** field .

I was set my view to enable ajax validation.

my problem is the ajax validation applied for all field not only for email, I need to do this action only for one field onChange event.

this my view

```
$form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
                'id'=>'Login-Form',
                'enableClientValidation'=>true,
                'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
                'clientOptions'=>array(
                        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
                ),
        )); 
 echo $form->errorSummary($loginForm);

 echo $form->textFieldRow($loginForm, 'email'); 

 echo $form->textFieldRow($loginForm, 'name'); 

 echo $form->textFieldRow($loginForm, 'age'); 

 echo $form->textFieldRow($loginForm, 'country');
```

and this is my model

```
public function rules()
{
        return array(
            array('email, country, name', 'required'),
                        array('email', 'checkEmail')
                    );
}
// custom function to check email
 public function checkEmail($attribute, $params)      
 {  
            $this->addError($attribute,strtr('email exsit before',$params));
 }
```

how can enable ajax validation only for email and the other filed (country, name, age) on client side without ajax validation.

Please help I send a lot of time to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Set the form clientOption on change like this:

```
$form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
            'id'=>'Login-Form',
            'enableClientValidation'=>true,
            'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
            'clientOptions'=>array(
                    'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
                    'validateOnChange'=>true,
```

So that on change it can trigger the validation
This can be done by setting the 4th parameter to false on validate trigger.

```
<?php echo $form->error($model,'email', array(), false); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still validate all field, and when onChange event on any field ajax request sent to server, so I have a lot of ajax request validation, I need one ajax request to validate only an email.

Comment: we can add 'validateOnType'=>true, so it will show error while typing.

Answer (score 0):

In your model set this

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
               array('email, country, name', 'required'),
               array('email', 'unique'), //check if email already exist
               array('email', 'email'),
        );
    }
```

in your controller

```
    <?php 
    class SiteController extends CController {
    .... // Other functions

    public function actionLogin(){  // Your corresponding action
        $model= new LoginForm();  // Your actual model name

        $_POST['ajax'] === 'Login-form' make sure that login form is the same as your form name in view 

         if (isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] === 'Login-form') {
         echo CActiveForm::validate($model,);
         Yii::app()->end();
    }

    ... // Remaining action logic
```

in your view

```
    $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'Login-Form',
        'enableClientValidation'=>false,
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
        'clientOptions'=>array(
            'validateOnSubmit'=>false,
            'validateOnChange'=>false,
            'validateOnType' => true,
```

Answer (score -1):

To perform validation via ajax you first need to call a helper function in your controller in addition to you enabling the `enableAjaxValidation` in your form view

In your Controller ( I am assuming the SiteController since this a login form )

```
<?php 
class SiteController extends CController {
.... // Other functions

public function actionLogin(){  // Your corresponding action
    $model= new LoginForm();  // Your actual model name

    if (isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] === 'login-form') {
         echo CActiveForm::validate($model,array('email'));
         Yii::app()->end();
    }

    ... // Remaining action logic
```

see [Validate](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#validate-detail) and [enableAjaxValidation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#enableAjaxValidation-detail) api docs for full details how this works